# what user is php-fpm running in docker or without docker?

Tags: php, linux, docker, nginx, permissions

```
RUN groupadd -g 1000 www
RUN useradd -u 1000 -ms /bin/bash -g www www
COPY . /var/www
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www
USER www
```

In dockerfile, I got this.

My question is: how to check which user is running under php-fpm container? In nginx, if I want to find that out, I check /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file and there's user written there. but for php-fpm I can't figure out.  **How do I figure out?** Don't tell me to use whoami or things like that as this is the user that is currently logged in.

The command I showed you above (i don't know how it does) but it makes www user and www group and gives this user and group to all my files and directories. then sets the USER which will be logged in. but I don't know how 'write' permission works, as folders have `rwxr-xr-x.` this means that php-fpm is running under www.  We never changed which user is running under php-fpm and how does it happen? Can someone explain that to me?

Comment: I’d expect the process to run with a uid of 1000 and for the container to believe that user is named `www`, following the Dockerfile instructions.  Is there a reason to believe that’s not happening?

Comment: The thing is php-fpm runs php scripts as www user. because i changed permissions on folders and it stopped working as soon as I changed the first 3 bits(it was rwx and i set ---). and for others I set(rwx). If it was running other user than www, it would still work. So php-fpm is runnning under www. but I don't know how that happens. when did we changed it to run under www or is it default from php-fpm docker image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker is in isolation technology, but you still can use `ps -ef` and so on, so just run

```
docker exec -it ${container} ps -ef
```

and it will return the list of active processes and their owners.

For example simple `php:8-fpm` shows:

```
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root           1       0  0 05:16 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: master 
process (/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf)
www-data       7       1  0 05:16 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data       8       1  0 05:16 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
```

Next just find the user in the `/etc/passwd`

```
docker exec -it ${container} grep 'www-data' /etc/passwd
```

It will show

```
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

So it's definitely www-data with uid 33.

If the container doesn't have `ps` inside, you have 2 options, you can install it, or find uid manually

For install use this command (example is for `php:8-fpm`):

```
docker exec -it -u 0 ${container} su -c "apt update -y && apt install procps -y"
```

For manual search just grep `/proc`

```
sudo docker exec -it ${container} ls -ln /proc/
```

`php:8-fpm` as other containers run a forked process as non-root, so the user won't be 0, in this case, 33

Comment: php-fpm doesn't have ps . I should install it and change image . which i don't want to do.

Comment: /proc/7/status - no such file or directory.

Comment: U need to update your linux knowledge. Login to the container and grep content from proc. ps axu do the same. so docker exec container ls -l /proc/. u will see www-data, it's enough to be sure 100%

Comment: I did it when you previously told me that and there's www permissions. so It's running under www right?

Comment: which one image do u use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190102/discussion-between-nika-khurashvili-and-dmitrii).

Comment: I get this when running ps axu: `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "ps": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`

Answer (score 0):

`USER www` changes the user the container runs as to `www`. If php-fpm is run as non-root then it will ignore the `user` and `group` directives for the pool config and run instead as the current user. Those directives only apply if php-fpm is run as root.

The standard php-fpm docker container runs as root but has the pool configured to for `www-data`.